# Oracle Select before update

Tags: oracle

In Oracle is there way to select a data set and use it for update like in the Merge statement.

I'm looking for something like

```
USING
(
SELECT a, b, c FROM t
)
UPDATE t1
SET t1.x = t.a,
t1.y = t.b;
```

Comment: To do an update "like in a Merge statement" why not use a merge statement? The `when matched` and `when not matched` clauses are both optional. To do an update without insert, use the just the `when matched` clause.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you just want to

```
UPDATE t1
   SET (x, y) = (SELECT a, b
                   FROM t
                  WHERE t.some_column = t1.some_column);
```

If you only want to update rows in T1 if there is a matching row in T

```
UPDATE t1
   SET (x, y) = (SELECT a, b
                   FROM t
                  WHERE t.some_column = t1.some_column)
 WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
     FROM t
    WHERE t.some_column = t1.some_column );
```

If your SELECT from `T` returns a single row, you can omit the WHERE clause that joins the two tables.

Comment: This should solve my problem but i'm worried about the performance. This is a correlated subquery which is very heavy unlike the select clause in a merge statement. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Avinash - It should be no more efficient to do a MERGE that only does UPDATES (whether that's legal syntax depends on the Oracle version) than to do a correlated update.